# Codeigniter not loading view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some code that grabs a webpage and saves it to the CI application/views folder. My plan is to make some changes dynamically and then redisplay the page. However when I try to load the page I get a blank page. I can see that 'newpage.php' is created as expected in the views folder. Here's the code:

```
$returned_content = get_data('http://www.yahoo.com');   // THIS USES CURL
file_put_contents(APPPATH."views/newpage.php", $returned_content);
$this->load->view('newpage');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Addendum: In case Povilas was correct about the preloading of views I added a view named 'html_template' with code

```
<?php echo $htmlstring; ?>
```

I changed the code to

```
$returned_content = get_data('http://www.yahoo.com');   // THIS USES CURL
$data=array('htmlstring'=>$returned_content);
$this->load->view('html_template', $data);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, I can see that 'newpage.php' is created as expected in the views folder, and it contains the correct content. Also If I open the created with with a browser it opens normally

Comment: Try to add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of this file, maybe there's an error.

Comment: You said the file is made correctly, if you *just* have `$this->load->view('newpage');` (without the 1st two lines), does it work?

Comment: I commented out the first 2 lines, with newpage.php in the views folder. The only remaining line is $this->load->view('newpage'); It still does not load.

Comment: What's inside `newpage.php`?  Maybe it didn't download/save correctly.

Comment: I got it working, code posted above. In case Povilas was correct about the preloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that CodeIgniter actually "preloads" the views in the beginning, so you cannot create it on the fly?

Another theory - could it be that loading the view is executed earlier than file creation operation actually finishes?

Couldn't you create the view from the start and just pass the $returned_content to the view?